# What's the measure of the segment $ON$ in the circle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:On the circle with center $O$ and perpendicular diameters
perpendiculars $AC$ and $BD$ a string $AE (E~ in~ \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{BC})$ is drawn
such that AE intersects $BD$ at $M$; if $BM = MO$. Calculate $ON$, if $OA = 12$. ($N =ED\cap AC$).

My progress:

[image]
$\triangle ABO(right): AB = 12\sqrt2 = AD\\\triangle ABM \sim \triangle DME (A.A)\\
\frac{12\sqrt2}{DE} = \frac{BM}{ME} = \frac{AM}{DM}\\
\angle ABD = \angle BEA = \angle AED =45^o\\
\angle DBE = \angle OND \implies\\
\frac{ON}{BE}=\frac{DN}{24}=\frac{6}{DE}$

Extend $DC$ and $AE (F=DC \cap AE)$

$\angle MAD = \angle AND\\
\triangle NOD \sim \triangle ADF \implies: \frac{OD}{ON} = \frac{FD}{AD}\implies ON = \frac{144\sqrt2}{FD}...$

Comment: @MathLover  Forgive me it was a typo  $(E~ in~ \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{BC})$

Comment: @MathLover  is it possible reolution by geomtry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $\angle OAM =\alpha, \angle EAB =\beta.$
We have $\tan\alpha =\frac{|MO|}{|OA|} =\frac{1}{2}$ thus $\cos\alpha =2\sin\alpha$ and hence $$\sin\alpha =\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} , \cos\alpha =\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}.$$
Now $$\sin\beta =\sin (\frac{\pi }{4} -\alpha ) =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5} -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10},\cos\beta = \frac{3\sqrt{10}}{10}$$

Now it is easy to observe that $\angle BDE =\beta$ and hence
$$\frac{|ON|}{|OD|} =\tan\beta =\frac{1}{3}$$
therefore $$|ON| =4.$$

Comment: Forgive me it was a typo  $(E~ in~ \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{BC})$..but thanks for resolution

Answer (score 3):

Please note that $\angle DEC = \angle DAC = 45^\circ$

So, $EN$ is angle bisector of $\angle AEC$. Also, $\triangle AEC \sim \triangle AOM$

So, $ \displaystyle \frac{AN}{NC} = \frac{AE}{EC} = \frac{AO}{OM} = 2$

Leads to $AN = 2 NC \implies NC = 8 $ and $ON = 4$

Comment: just a suggestion - if you seek a geometric solution, you should wait for sometime to get a geometric solution before accepting an answer :)

Comment: ok...I will wait a little longer...But I think that for the forum the trigonometric answers have value...so some of them I accept and also for the effort dedicated by those who answered...I will mention in the statement that preferably the question should be solved by geometry, so there is no "weight" (it is a particular feeling of mine) of not accepting an answer just because it is through trigonometry. Regards

Answer (score 2):

We need only the simple picture:

[image: math stackexchange some geometry problem]

$$
\frac{ON}{12}
=
\frac{ON}{OD}
=\tan\delta=\tan(45^\circ-\alpha)
=\frac{\tan 45^\circ -\tan \alpha}{1+\tan 45^\circ \tan \alpha}
=\frac {1-(1/2)}{1+(1/2)}=\frac {1/2}{3/2}=\frac 13\ .
$$
So $ON=4$.

$\square$